# Selection list dependant input element using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have symptom_id, symptom, duration, prompt and reference text as the structure of my sql table. its already populated with many rows and on the interface, i need to select a symtom that will trigger it duration in another input that will in turn trigger its prompt in another input that will in turn trigger its reference text as per the row in the database.
After that, i add another row on the interface using java script. the code is below

```
  function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","pages/triage/get_prompt.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

/***Ends here **/

```
function addRow(tableID) {


        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
           // alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 2) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

i really need your help.
So far i can add a new row successfully, but the problem is having the duration, prompt, and reference text auto-populate depending on the symptom.

Comment: This is pure js - not jquery (would be a lot easier if you used jQuery) - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for it.

Require jQuery from google CDN

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url_to_php",
  context: $('#form_id').serialize()
}).done(function() {
  alert( "done" );
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
  var_dump($_GET);
?>
```